# Accidentally contributed to a dependent care FSA instead of health/vision FSA, what are my options?

Tags: united-states, fsa

I put $750 into what I thought was a health/vision limited FSA this year through my employer. Apparently, this is *actually* a dependent care FSA. I don't know how this happened (whether it was my error or my companies error is not clear to me, I would not have intentionally signed up for dependent care FSA though).

I have no dependents and will have zero ability to use this money legitimately.

What are my options to recover this money?

Comment: whose mistake it was makes a big difference. If you filled out the form for the non-dependent one, and they put it in the wrong one, they can fix it. If you filled out the wrong form, there is no way they could have known.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I'm not sure who is at fault. I selected 2015 benefits through a phone conversation with a benefits person. But considering that was a year ago, I'm not sure what happened. I know for a fact I would not have intentionally signed up for the dependent care FSA (we have no kids...) but.. I don't remember what happened in that conversation.

Comment: I have never signed up via voice. I have always signed up via handwritten form, or via a website. Both of which leave you with proof.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep my plan is to call them Monday. I'm hoping this isn't a stupid tax over an otherwise minor mistake..

Comment: @enderland By "benefits person", was it someone at your company, and an informal call? If so, could you talk to them and ask them if there is any way for them to correct the mistake, regardless of who made it? Admit you're not sure where things went wrong, but are more interested in solving the problem than figuring blame. Or, if this "benefits person" was at some other company administering your employer's benefits, perhaps they should have a recording of the call and the error would be evident?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea we have an internal department (I guess you'd call it that) to facilitate all benefits. I had called them to setup my benefits. I plan on talking to them tomorrow and saying my situation. It's entirely possible that I am 100% to blame for this (inadvertently signing up for the wrong FSA or not asking the right question). Regardless I'm going to ask. Not having any dependents at all now or then makes it a lot easier to show it was a mistake hopefully... :-)

Comment: @mhoran_psprep it turns out in this case it was their mistake (and they had confirmation I selected the limited purpose health care FSA as my election). From the conversation I had, it sounds like this would have been... problematic if they didn't have that documentation. So I guess I'm lucky in this case..

Comment: @mhoran_psprep round two is fixing my W2 (see my self-answer here) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on this, here is what I did.

First, I called my benefits provider.

They had documentation of my election over the phone, which then allowed them to retroactively fix the problem. Had they not had this documentation, I would have been out of luck.

Second, the next step for "fixing" occurred when I received my W-2 for this position. This W-2 mistakenly showed the amount for my medical FSA in box-10 of my W-2 as the same dependent care FSA.

This requires calling/emailing my benefits and payroll department to get an updated W-2...